# Can you change the export template of a test suite in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

there is something that I want to change when exporting my list of test cases from Azure (via Right-clicking the suite -> Export -> Email (let's say)). I want to add a title and also something in the footer. Does somebody know if this is possible?

Thank you!